# Calling Method by using String instead of ObjectName - Processing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, string, methods, processing

I am trying to combine multiple sketches I had, by having them as classes in a single sketch and go through them by pressing keys.

I'm not sure I'm following the right method but I'm basically turning them on and off by using a boolean for each. I have something like:

```
package combiner;

public class Combiner extends PApplet {
    //...
    ClassNameOne s1;
    ClassNameTwo s2;
    //...
    ClassNameNine s9;

    // AllSketches //
    boolean[] sketches;
    int totalSketches = 9;
    String str_ts = String.valueOf(totalSketches);
    char char_ts = str_ts.charAt(0);

    public void setup() {
            size(1920, 1080);

            sketches = new boolean[totalSketches];
            for (int i = 0; i < sketches.length; i++) {
            sketches[i] = false;
            }

            s1 = new ClassNameOne(this);
            s2 = new ClassNameTwo(this);
            //...
            s9 = new ClassNameNine(this);
    }

    public void draw() {
            //drawingEachSketchIfItsBoolean==True
            if (sketches[0] == true) {
            s1.run();
            } else if (sketches[1] == true) {
            s2.run();
            //....
            }
    }

    public void keyPressed() {
            if (key >= '1' && key <= char_ts) {
                    String str_key = Character.toString(key);
                    int KEY = Integer.parseInt(str_key);

                    for (int i = 0; i < sketches.length; i++) {
                    sketches[i] = false;
                    }
                    sketches[KEY - 1] = true;

                    //initializingEachClassIfKeyPressed
                    if (KEY == 0) {
                    s1.init();
                    } else if (KEY == 1) {
                    s2.init();
                    }
                    //....
            }
    }
```

As you can see each Class has an .init and a .run method (used to be my setup + draw).
I was wandering if somehow I can loop to .init or .run them without having to write it once for each, something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<sketches.length;i++){
    if(sketches[i]==true){
        String str = String.valueOf(i+1);
        str="s"+str; //str becomes the Object's name
        ??? str.run(); ???
    }
}
```

Comment: if you look at the last for loop that I want to have in the draw method, you will see that what I want to do is loop through 9(or more) booleans, find then one that's true and run only that specific object. If boolean sketches[4]==true then s4.run(); So my question is not about getting the s4 instance's class but since I know the name of the instance as a string (str="s"+str) somehow go from there to running its method 'run'. Hope I was clearer.

Comment: Have you looked into the 'Mother" library ?? http://www.onar3d.com/mother/

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution would be to create an **interface Sketch**, which must be implemented in your sketch classes then:

```
Sketch[] sketches;
int activeSketch = 0;

void setup(){
  sketches = new Sketch[2];
  sketches[0] = new SketchRed();
  sketches[1] = new SketchGreen();
  sketches[activeSketch].init();
}

void draw(){
  sketches[activeSketch].draw();
}

interface Sketch{
  void init();
  void draw();
}

class SketchRed implements Sketch{
  void init(){}

  void draw(){
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, 30, 30);
  }
}

class SketchGreen implements Sketch{
  void init(){}

  void draw(){
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, 30, 30);
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  activeSketch++;
  if(activeSketch >= sketches.length){
    activeSketch = 0;
  }
  sketches[activeSketch].init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the whole idea of representing different sketches as classes in a new sketch is really that good, but in any case there seems to be a possibilty in Java for obtaining a class from a String! Look for `Class.forName()` as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.htm

Keep in mind that you will obtain a class from this and not an instance yet!

Comment: ok thanks, I already tried to implement that but wasn't able to figure out how yet. About the representing different sketches idea, I have a vjing event in 2 weeks and i found it an easy way to jump from 1 sketch to another without using another software.

Comment: If this is where you are stuck, please edit the question to reflect that too! If you have a problem getting the fully qualified class name that `Class.forName()` requires (something like 'abc.xyz.ClassName'), use e.g. `s1.getClass()` to obtain it. If this is not where you are stuck, then explain where else you need help!